# Python: Counting repeating values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, count, repeat

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
dictA = { ('unit1','test1') : 'alpha' , ('unit1','test2') : 'beta', ('unit2','test1') : 'alpha', ('unit2','test2') : 'gamma' , ('unit3','test1') : 'delta' , ('unit3','test2') : 'gamma'   }
```

How can I count the number of repeating values per each test independent of units?

i.e.

in 'test1' there is 2x 'alpha', 1x 'delta'

in 'test2' there is 1x 'beta', 2x 'gamma'

Any inputs?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2.7 or 3.1 or above, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter((k[1], v) for k, v in dictA.iteritems())
print(counts)
```

prints

```
Counter({('test1', 'alpha'): 2, ('test2', 'gamma'): 2, ('test2', 'beta'): 1, ('test1', 'delta'): 1})
```

Comment: In previous versions `collections.defaultdict(int)` worked similarly.