# Counting values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a dictionary where the values are lists, and I would like to count how many times each item appears in the list associated with each key.
For example:
 `my_dict= {10:[23,24,23,23,24],11:[17,23,23,17,24]}`
would generate `10:(23:3,24:2),11:(17:2,23:2,24:1)`

I have tried using

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter((k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items())
print(counts)
```

which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490078/python-counting-repeating-values-of-a-dictionary), but with no success, as the values are lists, so are unhashable. I have fiddled about with collections.Counter and the structure of the dictionary for a while now, but nothing seems to be working. All of the solutions I have found online have been for dictionaries with one value per key, and for duplicates in the whole dictionary, not per key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_dict= {10:[23,24,23,23,24],11:[17,23,23,17,24]}
>>> {k: Counter(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{10: Counter({23: 3, 24: 2}), 11: Counter({17: 2, 23: 2, 24: 1})}
```

Comment: Excellent! It's slightly embarrassing how simple that was :p Thank you!

Comment: @Snaaa The error message must have thrown you off :) Since Counter was trying to count the actual tuples themselves which were key pair values and the value was a list which is unhashable.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = {k:Counter(v) for (k,v) in my_dict.items()}
```